# Try catch working differently in separate environments while checking if array key exists

Tags: php, docker, config, php-7.1

We have a strange issue with php.

We have a docker container that runs our code for local dev purposes, and we deploy this container to a rancher environment for acceptance and production.

We have the following habit to check if a key in an associative array exists:

```
try {
    $value = $someArray['does']['this']['exist'];
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // No it didn't, do something else
    $value = 'fallback';
}
```

This is just a shortcut and prevents that we need to check if all of those keys exist.

This works perfectly in our local dev environment. But not when it's deployed to our acceptance or production environment. It will never reach the catch. In this case, `$value` will be null.

How come the same docker container behaves differently when it's deployed?

EDIT (added docker-compose info)

```
# docker/docker-compose.yml
version: "2"

services:
  api-tools:
    container_name: api-tools
    image: bizz-registry.githost.io/neon/api-tools:acceptance
    env_file: [".env"]
    ports:
      - 8005:80
    environment:
      SYMFONY_DEBUG: "true"
      SYMFONY_ENV: "dev"
    restart: on-failure:10
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/webapp:cached
      - ./web/app_dev.php:/opt/webapp/web/app.php
      - ./docker/vhost.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
      - ./docker/development/development.override:/etc/apache2/sites-available/development.override
      - ./docker/development/development.opcache.override:/etc/php/7.1/fpm/conf.d/tweak-opcache.ini
    working_dir: "/opt/webapp"
    external_links: [ mysql ]
    command: "/usr/bin/env php -d open_basedir= vendor/phing/phing/bin/phing setup run"
```

This is what `setup` calls:

```
<target name="setup">
        <exec command="php ${project.basedir}/bin/console cache:warmup --env=prod" passthru="true" checkreturn="true" />
    </target>
```

This is what `run` calls:

```
<target name="run">
        <exec command="/opt/start.sh" passthru="true" checkreturn="true" />
        <exec command="/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND" passthru="true" checkreturn="true" />
    </target>
```

Comment: Please, put your Dockerfile, `docker run` line or docker-compose.yml file to see how do you run container

Comment: Ok, added info to OP :)

Comment: Undefined index doesn't throw at your production environment. 
Just use `$value = $someArray['does']['this']['exist'] ?? 'fallback'` . That's the way to go here. 
(PHP 7.0, null coalescing https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php). If you _must_ use this approach, you've to set a PHP error handler check whether it's an 'undefined index' error and throw from the hander.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great alternative. We might add this php error handler check to prevent changing the codebase too much. I will look into that.

Comment: Note that you've mounting volumes that depends on which directory do you execute `docker run`. So, it's recommended to put in volumes section absolute paths